# AWS VPC Peering routing table creation throttling

Tags: amazon-web-services, delay, aws-vpc-peering

We are hitting connectivity issues in vpc peering when it is re-created. The exact steps are:

1. Create peering between vpc's A & B
2. Delete peering between A & B
3. Create peering between vpc's A & B

There is hardly any time gap between these steps. After step 3, I can see the peering status as "Active", however there is a delay in populating routing tables (which is done by AWS). The delay of more than 10 min is not uncommon. All this is in us-east-1 region.

More context: The above steps are part of test automation and hence many such requests are fired.

Has anyone faced this issue? Does AWS throttle internally?

Comment: It's probably not intentional "throttling", but there would be stuff done to provision the VPC Peering connection. You will likely need to introduce a 'wait' step in your testing.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Interestingly, the peering in first step is alright most of the time but the second peering has the issue.